# I have a Windows host and I want to bind a client virtual machine's IP to the host's 127.0.0.2 address

Tags: windows, networking

I have a Windows 10 computer. I added a client Linux virtual machine and I want to be able to connect from the host to the client at 127.0.0.2:22. I need to use the 127.0.0.* range because my VPN is disabling accessing the 192.* and 10.* while activated.

I installed the Windows loopback adapter and I've identified the network that corresponds to the loopback network. But I can't figure out how to configure the loopback network. I believe I'd disable all items except the IPv4 item, but I'm unable to explicitly bind on 127.

Comment: Does your VPN disable the *other* private ranges, 172.16./12 and 100.64./10? There are various options but trying to repurpose 127.x is probably the worst of them (as it's one of the few ranges with special treatment in every OS).

Comment: _127.0.0.0/8_ are special addresses exclusively for loopback. You will not be able to use them. Use a different network range instead like user1686 suggested. You could also use real internet IP addresses if you never want to contact them, like Google DNS or Cloudflare DNS or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

The solution might be to create an alternative loopback interface
that is not bound to `127.x.x.x`, giving it an IP address that the
VPN does not block (if one exists).

Note that two loopback interfaces might have a problem to communicate
one with the other.

For instructions on doing that using PowerShell, see the article
[Create Loopback Interface with PowerShell](https://gbe0.com/posts/windows/server-windows/create-loopback-interface-with-powershell/).

The linked article explains well the process. I only include below
the bare PowerShell commands. Replace the IP address with one that
is not blocked:

```
# The name for the loopback adapter interface that will be created.
$loopback_name = 'Loopback'

# The name for the servers main network interface. This will be updated to allow weak host send/recieve which is most likely required for the traffic to work for the loopback interface.
$primary_interface = 'Ethernet'

# The IPv4 address that you would like to assign to the loopback interface along with the prefix length (eg. if the IP is routed to the server usually you would set the prefix length to 32).
$loopback_ipv4 = '10.254.1.3'
$loopback_ipv4_length = '32'

# The IPv6 address that you would like to assign to the loopback interface along with the prefix length (eg. if the IP is routed to the server usually you would set the prefix length to 128). If you are not adding an IPv6 address do not set these variables.
# $loopback_ipv6 = 'fffa::1'
# $loopback_ipv6_length = '128'

Install-Module -Name LoopbackAdapter -MinimumVersion 1.2.0.0 -Force
Import-Module -Name LoopbackAdapter

New-LoopbackAdapter -Name $loopback_name -Force

$interface_loopback = Get-NetAdapter -Name $loopback_name
$interface_main = Get-NetAdapter -Name $primary_interface

Set-NetIPInterface -InterfaceIndex $interface_loopback.ifIndex -InterfaceMetric "254" -WeakHostReceive Enabled -WeakHostSend Enabled -DHCP Disabled
Set-NetIPInterface -InterfaceIndex $interface_main.ifIndex -WeakHostReceive Enabled -WeakHostSend Enabled
Set-NetIPAddress -InterfaceIndex $interface_loopback.ifIndex -SkipAsSource $True

Get-NetAdapter $loopback_name | Set-DNSClient –RegisterThisConnectionsAddress $False

# Set the IPv4 address
New-NetIPAddress -InterfaceAlias $loopback_name -IPAddress $loopback_ipv4 -PrefixLength $loopback_ipv4_length -AddressFamily ipv4

# Set the IPv6 address - Uncomment this if required
# New-NetIPAddress -InterfaceAlias $loopback_name -IPAddress $loopback_ipv6 -PrefixLength $loopback_ipv6_length -AddressFamily ipv6

Disable-NetAdapterBinding -Name $loopback_name -ComponentID ms_msclient
Disable-NetAdapterBinding -Name $loopback_name -ComponentID ms_pacer
Disable-NetAdapterBinding -Name $loopback_name -ComponentID ms_server
Disable-NetAdapterBinding -Name $loopback_name -ComponentID ms_lltdio
Disable-NetAdapterBinding -Name $loopback_name -ComponentID ms_rspndr
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this.

On almost all systems, the 127.0.0.0/8 network is connected to the loopback-interface. The only system connected to this interface is the system itsself. Not the virtual machines. Your Linux virtual machine has its own loopback-interface, with its own 127.0.0.0/8 network. The two networks are not connected to each other.

Although it is possible to put he 127.0.0.0/8 network on another interface than loopback, certain software (VirtualBox for example) will break. And you must be very sure of what you are doing. Note that it will not be sufficient to do this on the Windows host only; you must also do that on the Linux virtual machine.

Instead, try to use a subnet of 100.64.0.0/10 or 172.16.0.0/12, as user1686 suggested in the comments.